# extract values from json using Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, hash, key

I need to extract only the value for 'admins' from this Json using Ruby :

JSON -

```
 {
    "Roles":[
        {
             "admins":[
                "me"
            ],
        "role":"cleanup"
        },
    {
        "admins":[
            "tester"
        ],
        "role":"create a mess"
    },
       ]
```

}

RUBY -

```
require 'json'
file = File.read('adminlist_Feb_2017.json')
thismonthlist=JSON.parse(file)
puts thismonthlist['admins']
```

Output - this gives me a blank output however if i change the last line to :
       puts thismonthlist['Roles']

it gives me everything. I just want the list of admins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
admins = []
File.open('adminlist_Feb_2017.json', 'r') do |file|
  json = JSON.parse(file.read)
  admins = json["Roles"].flat_map{|role| role["admins"]}.uniq
end

admins
# => ["me", "tester"]
```

I open the file and process it in a block to ensure it's closed at the end. In the block I read the file content and parse the json string into a hash. Then I go through the "Roles" of the hash, grab the "admins" arrays and return it as one array only with [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map). After I use [Enumerable#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-uniq) to return each admin only once.

Comment: Thanks,works like a charm! Just need to figure out how to remove leading spaces and general cleanup of 'admins' now. Much appreciated!

Comment: I mean remove leading spaces from the admins? Try: `[" me ", "    tester   "].map{|admin| admin.strip} # => ["me", "tester"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
 thismonthlist[:Roles].flat_map { |role| role[:admins] }
 => ["me", "tester"]
```